Connecting to a Cisco Switch Using LDAP Authentication via FreeRADIUS
I have a problem with my FreeRADIUS server. I would like to connect to my Cisco switches using LDAP authentication from my FreeRADIUS server, but only for people who are part of a specific group. I have looked around and found this.
220 authorize {
221
222     ldap
223     if (LDAP-Group == "GROUPE") {
224         update control {
225             Auth-Type := Accept
226         }
227     }
228     else {
229         reject
230     }

Could someone please help me? :)
I have also linked my Active Directory, but when I enter my LDAP credentials on the Cisco switch, it says that the login information is invalid, even though it matches my LDAP credentials. I tested by creating a local user on the server, and it works. I also tested the credentials used to link my LDAP with ldapsearch, and it works fine.
